# How to shade above a plotted line?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a  grid with a line drawn on it as follows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Draw squares with random integers between -3 and 3 in each square
np.random.seed(42)  # Setting a seed for reproducibility
square = np.zeros((10, 10), dtype=np.int_)
for x in np.arange(0.5, 10, 1):
    for y in np.arange(0.5, 10, 1):
        value = np.random.randint(-3, 4)
        square[int(x), int(y)] = value
        plt.text(x-0.2, y-0.2, str(value), ha='center', va='center', fontsize=8, color='black')
        
# Calculate the center coordinates and add blue dots
for x in np.arange(0.5, 10, 1):
    for y in np.arange(0.5, 10, 1):
        plt.scatter(x, y, color='blue', s=1)  # Adjust the size (s) as needed
        


x_points = [7, 2]
y_points = [0, 10]
plt.plot(x_points, y_points)

# Customize the plot
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 10.01, 1))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 10.01, 1))
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.grid()
```

It looks like:

[image]

I would like to shade the region that is above the line (that is the region that includes the top left square).  How can you do that?

Comment: `plt.fill_betweenx(y_points, x_points)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`plt.fill_betweenx()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_betweenx.html) like this:

```py
plt.fill_betweenx(y_points, x_points)
```

Output:
[image: Output]

However, this means that the points in the filled area can't be seen. One way you could fix this is by adding opacity:

```py
plt.fill_betweenx(y_points, x_points, alpha=0.3)
```

[image: Output]

Full code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Draw squares with random integers between -3 and 3 in each square
np.random.seed(42)  # Setting a seed for reproducibility
square = np.zeros((10, 10), dtype=np.int_)
for x in np.arange(0.5, 10, 1):
    for y in np.arange(0.5, 10, 1):
        value = np.random.randint(-3, 4)
        square[int(x), int(y)] = value
        plt.text(x - 0.2, y - 0.2, str(value), ha='center', va='center', fontsize=8, color='black')

# Calculate the center coordinates and add blue dots
for x in np.arange(0.5, 10, 1):
    for y in np.arange(0.5, 10, 1):
        plt.scatter(x, y, color='blue', s=1)  # Adjust the size (s) as needed

x_points = [7, 2]
y_points = [0, 10]
plt.plot(x_points, y_points)
plt.fill_betweenx(y_points, x_points, alpha=0.3)  # <--

# Customize the plot
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 10.01, 1))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 10.01, 1))
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.grid()
```